# Edit a classes return (python)

Tags: python

In my python project I am trying to create a colour class to store rgb values

when called I want it to return (r,g,b)

without creating a function within the class to return the values e.g.

```
var = colour(r,g,b) 
var.getcolour() #would represent (r,g,b)
```

but rather

```
var = colour(r,g,b)
var #would represent (r,g,b)
```

would there be maybe a built in class function that I could override?
similar to __ eq__, __ add__, __ sub__ etc...

Comment: Yes: `__str__`.

Comment: Also it's a good practice to have your classes names capitalized: `Colour`.